# Linux: Conda not working on installing Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda for python2 as per official [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux). In the end I received message about successful installation. To check I typed `ipython` and its terminal is displayed successfully but on doing `conda --version` nothing comes. I have checked following:

1. `which python` : It gives `/home/username/anaconda2/bin/python`
2. sha of downloaded package: It is correct
3. Other Anaconda installed package (ipython): It's terminal comes up
4. `which conda`: `/home/username/anaconda2/bin/conda`
5. Closed terminal and again open it(mentioned in docs). Checked after shutdown also !
6. On doing `anaconda-navigator` following message comes:

   `Please activate the conda root enviroment properly before running the
    anaconda-navigator command.`

   `To activate the environment please open a terminal and run:`

   `source /home/username/anaconda2/bin/activate root`

   `For more information please see the documentation at:`

   `https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/`

On doing as suggested above, nothing happens and the problem persists. Since I am new to this, might be missing something tivial, please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue on Ubuntu 17.04 x64. In my case it was the usage of a different shell than the default (bash).
I installed the program using my ZSH shell.
During installation it asks:

> Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda<2 or 3> install
>   location to PATH in your /home/user/.bashrc ?

That made me try to run the Anaconda Navigator using bash shell (just use the `bash` command to switch). And yes it worked.

If you look into the .bashrc you will notice that the installer appended something like:

```
export PATH="/home/user/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

If you export the path to ZSH (or any other shell you use) then it will work with your shell as well. In the case of ZSH just copy the *export PATH* line to the end of .zshrc